# Get minimum number column wise in a multidimensional Pandas DataFrame - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Pandas. I am trying to get the minimum number column-wise. So these are the steps I have followed:

1. I read the files from CSV files using

   data = [pd.read_csv(f, index_col=None, header=None) for f in temp]
2. Then added it to another data frame `flow = pd.DataFrame(data)`, making it "3d" data-frame.

So, `data` has `[128 rows x 14 columns] * 60 samples` with out `index_col` and `header`

One of the samples is:

```
[          0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      11      12      13
0    3985.1  4393.3  4439.5  3662.1  5061.0  3990.8  4573.8  4036.9  4717.9  4225.6  4638.5  4157.9  4496.4  4007.7
1    3998.5  4398.5  4447.2  3660.0  5062.6  3986.7  4573.3  4045.1  4733.8  4238.5  4650.3  4167.2  4509.2  4022.6
2    3995.4  4397.9  4442.1  3659.5  5058.5  3987.2  4569.7  4039.5  4724.1  4234.9  4645.6  4161.5  4506.2  4014.9
3    3985.1  4396.9  4432.3  3660.0  5054.9  3988.2  4568.2  4037.9  4719.0  4230.3  4632.3  4150.8  4500.5  4004.1
4    3985.1  4391.3  4428.2  3661.5  5057.9  3987.2  4570.8  4044.6  4731.3  4236.9  4631.8  4151.8  4503.1  4005.6
5    3991.3  4391.8  4430.8  3662.6  5059.5  3987.7  4572.8  4044.6  4730.8  4237.4  4639.5  4157.4  4507.2  4009.7
6    3989.7  4396.9  4436.9  3661.5  5057.4  3987.7  4571.3  4035.4  4716.9  4230.3  4641.0  4156.9  4505.1  4010.8
7    3983.6  4392.8  4435.4  3660.0  5056.9  3987.2  4570.8  4032.8  4719.5  4227.7  4634.4  4153.8  4497.4  4008.2
8    3983.1  4388.7  4428.7  3661.5  5056.9  3987.7  4571.8  4041.0  4728.2  4231.8  4631.3  4154.4  4499.0  4004.6
9    3988.2  4395.9  4433.3  3662.1  5057.9  3987.7  4572.3  4040.5  4720.5  4231.3  4636.9  4154.9  4503.1  4005.1
10   3988.7  4398.5  4439.0  3660.0  5060.0  3986.7  4572.3  4032.3  4710.3  4225.1  4640.5  4154.9  4497.4  4008.2
11   3983.6  4391.3  4434.4  3661.0  5059.0  3988.7  4570.3  4041.0  4724.6  4235.4  4642.6  4163.1  4499.5  4010.8
12   3984.1  4388.7  4432.8  3664.1  5058.5  3991.8  4574.4  4051.8  4740.5  4245.1  4645.1  4170.8  4507.7  4014.4
13   3986.7  4390.8  4432.8  3664.1  5057.9  3991.3  4583.1  4043.1  4724.6  4231.8  4642.1  4161.5  4505.6  4012.8
14   3984.6  4395.4  4433.8  3661.5  5059.0  3991.3  4583.1  4036.9  4713.8  4222.1  4641.0  4157.4  4503.1  4010.8
15   3989.2  4400.5  4440.0  3661.0  5066.7  3994.4  4579.5  4045.1  4732.8  4233.8  4648.2  4170.3  4509.2  4016.4
16   3990.8  4394.4  4437.4  3661.5  5071.8  3996.4  4580.5  4045.1  4738.5  4239.5  4650.3  4171.3  4509.7  4016.4
17   3979.0  4383.6  4426.7  3660.0  5065.6  3995.4  4577.4  4034.4  4715.4  4228.2  4643.6  4158.5  4504.6  4005.1
18   3972.8  4383.1  4426.2  3660.0  5057.9  3991.8  4569.7  4034.4  4712.3  4228.2  4639.5  4157.9  4502.6  3999.0
19   3982.6  4386.7  4430.3  3661.5  5055.9  3987.2  4568.7  4045.6  4737.4  4243.1  4641.0  4166.7  4504.1  4007.7
20   3990.3  4389.7  4432.3  3661.5  5059.5  3989.7  4571.8  4047.2  4740.5  4245.1  4647.2  4169.2  4506.2  4014.9
21   3989.2  4392.8  4435.4  3661.0  5066.7  3996.9  4573.8  4035.9  4713.8  4232.3  4650.3  4166.7  4505.6  4014.4
22   3989.7  4391.8  4435.4  3661.5  5069.7  3997.4  4571.8  4035.4  4711.8  4231.3  4647.2  4167.7  4507.7  4017.4
23   3990.8  4389.7  4432.8  3660.0  5069.2  3996.9  4569.2  4044.6  4734.9  4237.9  4646.2  4168.7  4509.7  4020.0
24   3988.7  4393.3  4434.9  3659.0  5070.3  4000.5  4570.8  4041.0  4725.6  4232.8  4648.2  4166.7  4504.6  4016.4
25   3990.3  4397.9  4440.0  3661.0  5065.6  3997.9  4571.8  4039.0  4713.8  4230.8  4650.3  4169.7  4506.7  4019.0
26   3990.8  4396.4  4437.4  3662.1  5057.9  3988.7  4572.3  4045.1  4729.2  4236.4  4648.2  4169.7  4509.2  4022.6
27   3984.6  4385.1  4425.6  3661.5  5056.4  3990.8  4577.4  4041.5  4727.2  4231.8  4641.5  4158.5  4495.4  4010.3
28   3983.6  4381.0  4424.6  3662.1  5057.4  3999.5  4585.1  4037.4  4716.9  4229.7  4641.5  4157.4  4491.8  4006.2
29   3991.8  4391.3  4434.9  3662.1  5056.9  4000.0  4588.7  4040.5  4723.1  4234.4  4647.7  4167.7  4503.1  4017.4
..      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
98   3988.2  4372.3  4424.1  3662.1  5040.5  3989.2  4585.6  4033.3  4719.0  4233.3  4647.2  4163.6  4502.1  4011.8
99   3993.8  4382.1  4429.2  3660.5  5042.1  3988.2  4590.3  4045.1  4737.4  4255.9  4659.0  4176.9  4514.4  4021.5
100  3992.8  4384.1  4430.3  3661.0  5041.0  3989.7  4601.5  4039.5  4733.3  4264.1  4663.1  4186.2  4512.3  4023.6
101  3988.2  4374.9  4424.6  3663.6  5040.0  3991.3  4601.0  4028.7  4719.0  4247.7  4654.9  4171.8  4505.1  4017.4
102  3989.7  4374.9  4427.2  3662.1  5040.5  3990.8  4590.3  4033.3  4716.9  4234.4  4654.4  4168.7  4508.7  4015.9
103  3987.2  4372.3  4428.7  3660.5  5036.4  3988.2  4585.1  4035.9  4719.5  4231.8  4651.3  4171.3  4504.6  4012.8
104  3979.5  4365.6  4421.5  3662.1  5030.3  3984.1  4586.2  4030.3  4717.4  4229.7  4641.0  4158.5  4491.8  4005.6
105  3982.1  4372.8  4420.5  3662.1  5032.3  3974.9  4586.2  4034.4  4719.0  4233.8  4640.0  4155.4  4495.4  4006.2
106  3987.7  4380.0  4427.7  3659.5  5037.9  3973.8  4584.1  4039.0  4720.5  4241.0  4644.1  4165.1  4509.2  4010.8
107  3987.2  4374.4  4428.7  3662.6  5039.5  3982.6  4585.1  4034.4  4719.0  4233.3  4641.5  4158.5  4506.7  4007.7
108  3982.6  4370.8  4420.0  3664.1  5036.9  3982.6  4587.7  4034.9  4724.1  4228.7  4639.0  4150.8  4495.4  4000.5
109  3979.0  4372.3  4414.4  3658.5  5029.2  3971.8  4580.0  4037.4  4723.6  4233.8  4639.5  4154.9  4492.8  3997.4
110  3979.0  4374.4  4418.5  3658.5  5027.7  3970.3  4571.3  4029.7  4712.3  4225.6  4640.0  4155.4  4496.9  3998.5
111  3986.2  4381.0  4428.2  3663.1  5037.4  3980.5  4580.0  4025.6  4705.1  4217.9  4643.6  4157.9  4504.1  4003.1
112  3991.3  4383.6  4430.3  3661.5  5042.6  3985.6  4585.6  4027.2  4708.7  4225.6  4644.6  4166.7  4508.2  4007.2
113  3983.6  4378.5  4432.8  3659.0  5034.4  3976.9  4573.8  4032.8  4725.6  4236.9  4643.6  4165.6  4504.1  4005.1
114  3976.4  4380.0  4443.6  3661.0  5028.2  3968.7  4572.8  4037.4  4735.4  4247.2  4649.7  4168.2  4507.7  4008.2
115  3973.8  4378.5  4441.5  3661.5  5033.3  3974.4  4585.6  4028.2  4713.3  4236.9  4650.8  4170.8  4508.2  4004.1
116  3971.8  4370.3  4431.8  3661.0  5036.4  3983.6  4588.7  4019.0  4696.4  4212.3  4639.0  4159.0  4496.9  3991.8
117  3972.3  4371.8  4437.4  3661.0  5031.3  3982.1  4585.1  4032.3  4720.5  4218.5  4637.4  4155.9  4496.9  3994.9
118  3973.8  4379.0  4444.1  3660.5  5032.3  3980.0  4587.2  4041.0  4730.8  4236.9  4646.7  4166.7  4506.2  4006.7
119  3982.1  4385.1  4447.2  3661.5  5040.5  3984.1  4586.7  4024.6  4708.2  4230.3  4648.2  4168.7  4506.7  4010.3
120  3991.3  4390.8  4452.8  3663.1  5043.1  3985.1  4576.4  4019.0  4710.8  4228.2  4650.3  4168.7  4505.6  4011.8
121  3989.2  4386.7  4451.3  3660.5  5041.0  3981.5  4568.2  4032.3  4733.3  4237.9  4657.4  4172.8  4508.2  4011.3
122  3983.6  4384.1  4448.7  3658.5  5040.0  3982.6  4574.4  4036.9  4730.8  4237.4  4656.4  4172.3  4505.6  4008.7
123  3987.7  4391.3  4455.4  3661.0  5038.5  3984.6  4585.6  4029.7  4716.4  4231.3  4655.4  4171.3  4504.1  4012.8
124  3990.8  4392.8  4460.0  3660.0  5038.5  3983.6  4583.1  4026.2  4714.4  4231.3  4656.9  4172.3  4506.2  4013.8
125  3988.7  4390.8  4456.4  3657.9  5040.0  3984.6  4576.4  4025.1  4715.9  4231.3  4651.8  4167.2  4505.1  4012.8
126  3990.3  4393.8  4455.9  3659.0  5040.0  3983.1  4577.4  4026.7  4720.5  4231.8  4647.2  4167.2  4505.6  4018.5
127  3988.2  4392.8  4453.3  3660.0  5040.5  3976.9  4581.5  4033.8  4732.8  4235.4  4649.2  4170.8  4506.2  4015.9

[128 rows x 14 columns]]
```

I am trying to get the minimum number column-wise for every sample. How should I do it?

I tried using `min()`, by doing `data[0][0].min()` but I get the following as the output:

```
[[ 3985.1  4393.3  4439.5 ...,  4157.9  4496.4  4007.7]
 [ 3998.5  4398.5  4447.2 ...,  4167.2  4509.2  4022.6]
 [ 3995.4  4397.9  4442.1 ...,  4161.5  4506.2  4014.9]
 ..., 
 [ 3988.7  4390.8  4456.4 ...,  4167.2  4505.1  4012.8]
 [ 3990.3  4393.8  4455.9 ...,  4167.2  4505.6  4018.5]
 [ 3988.2  4392.8  4453.3 ...,  4170.8  4506.2  4015.9]]
```

It's same as the sample. I don't know what's the problem here.

Comment: Do you think `data[0][0].min(axis=1)`?

Comment: @jezrael I get an error `ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
print (data[0].min(axis=1))
0      3662.1
1      3660.0
2      3659.5
3      3660.0
4      3661.5
5      3662.6
6      3661.5
7      3660.0
8      3661.5
9      3662.1
10     3660.0
11     3661.0
12     3664.1
13     3664.1
14     3661.5
15     3661.0
...
...
```

Maybe beter is omit `flow = pd.DataFrame(data)` and use:

```
data = [pd.read_csv(f, index_col=None, header=None) for f in temp]

mins = [df.min(axis=1) for df in data[0]]
print (mins[0])
print (mins[1])
```

Comment: Nope.  I get `ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` error

Comment: I think when I add the list again to the data frame I am creating an extra dimension. If I do `mins = [df.min(axis=1) for df in data[0]]` then it's working.

Comment: Ok, super. One question - do you need work with `"3d" data-frame` ? Or better is create one big dataframe with all samples?

Comment: I don't have to work with `3d`, how am I suppose to do that? sorry very new to data frames!

Comment: No problem, we can find some solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124375/discussion-between-jezrael-and-akshay).